# Wait for gin HTTP server to start

Tags: go, channel, goroutine, httpserver, go-gin

We are using gin to expose some REST APIs in production. Now I have to do some stuff once the HTTP server starts.

I am not very familiar with channels, but given below code is what I'm trying to do. Once the `startHTPPRouter()` starts the HTTP service, I want to send a signal to `main()`. Based on that signal I want to do some other stuffs.

Please let me know what wrong I'm doing in the given below code.

```
func startHTTPRouter(routerChannel chan bool){
    router := gin.New()
    // Many REST API routes definitions
    router.Run("<port>")
    routerChannel <- true  // Is this gonna work ? Because Run() again launches a go routine for Serve()
}

func main() {
    routerChannel := make(chan bool)
    defer close(routerChannel)
    go startHTTPRouter(routerChannel )
    for {
        select {
        case <-routerChannel:
            doStuff()  // Only when the REST APIs are available.
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
        default:
            log.Info("Waiting for router channel...")
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `starts` mean?? :P once it is listening and accepting on a socket?  Once it is listening?

Answer (score -1):

gin.New().Run() is blocking API. gin server is not returned until exit.

```
func startHTTPRouter(routerChannel chan bool) {
    router := gin.New()
    router.Run("<port>")
    routerChannel <- true  // Is this gonna work ? Because Run() again launches a go routine for Serve()
}
```

Below is gin'Run() API. https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/master/gin.go

```
// Run attaches the router to a http.Server and starts listening and serving HTTP requests.
// It is a shortcut for http.ListenAndServe(addr, router)
// Note: this method will block the calling goroutine indefinitely unless an error happens.
func (engine *Engine) Run(addr ...string) (err error) {
    defer func() { debugPrintError(err) }()

    address := resolveAddress(addr)
    debugPrint("Listening and serving HTTP on %s\n", address)
    err = http.ListenAndServe(address, engine)
    return
}
```